# How to enlarge the font vertically in free pascal

Tags: fonts, freepascal

Im current using the "Printers" unit in Lazarus, for handling printing in my application. I need a way to enlarge the font vertically only, while keeping the same width. Im using the `Canvas.Font.Size` line to set the font-size, however i cant find a way to make the font grow only vertically. I tried using the `Canvas.Font.Height` property, but it's also making the font grow horizontally (width). Any idea?

Comment: lazarus\examples\lazfreetype, `WidthFactor` allows to change font ratio. Another way is to draw text on the image and then resample it.

Comment: Hey Abelisto, actually im looking for Height increase, not Width. About drawing to an image and re sample it, care to elaborate? Fairly new to Free Pascal. Thanks in advance!